# Converter valor para número retorna NaN

Tags: javascript

Estou lendo um livro sobre JavaScript, porém em determinada parte o código que consta no livro não funciona.

A parte é:

```
var qtyElements = produto[i].getElementsByClassName("quantity");
var qtyText = qtyElements[0].value;
var quantity = moneyTextToFloat(qtyText);
console.log(quantity);
```

Era para retornar a quantidade de uma classe, porém no console me retorna `NaN`.

Código completo:

```js
function moneyTextToFloat(text){
  var clean = text.replace("R$","").replace(",",".");
  return parseFloat(clean);
}

function floatToMoney(value){
  var text = (value < 1 ? "0" : 0 ) + Math.floor(value * 100);
  text = "R$" + text;
  return text.substr(0, text.length -2) + "," + text.substr(-2);
}
function readTotal(){
  var total = document.getElementById("total");
  return moneyTextToFloat(total.innerHTML);
}
function writeTotal(value){
  var total = document.getElementById("total");
  total.innerHTML = floatToMoney(value);
}
var totalProdutos = 0;
var produto = document.getElementsByClassName("produto");
for (let i = 0; i < produto.length; i++){
  var priceElements = produto[i].getElementsByClassName("price");
  var priceText = priceElements[0].innerHTML;
  var price = moneyTextToFloat(priceText);


  var qtyElements = produto[i].getElementsByClassName("quantity");
  var qtyText = qtyElements[0].value;
  var quantity = moneyTextToFloat(qtyText);
  console.log(quantity);

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>BIBLIOTECA</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>
    <table>
      <tbody> 
        <tr class="produto">
          <td class="td"><div class="price">R$29,90</div></td>
          <td><input type="number" class="quantity"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="produto">
          <td><div class="price">R$59,90</div></td>
          <td> <input type="number" class="quantity">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="produto">
          <td><div class="price">R$99,90</div></td>
          <td><input type="number" class="quantity"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Total de compras</td>
        <td><div id="total">R$ 189,90</div></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/carrinhoDeCompra.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Os inputs não tem value por isso que retorna NaN. Coloque `values` nos inputs, ex: `value="10"` fica assim `<input type="number" class="quantity" value="10">`

Comment: É o que o vovô @LeoCaracciolo falou, mas para evitar o NaN, coloque uma [Avaliação de  curto-circuito](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avaliação_de_curto-circuito) na variável: `var qtyText = qtyElements[0].value || '0';`. Assim, se o campo for vazio, será igual a `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ele está retornando. Neste caso, parseFloat("") out parseFloat(null) retorna NaN, pois não há um número. NaN significa Not a Number. Então se você quer que o resultado seja zero quando não houver um número dentro do teu campo você pode:

1 - Forçar zero caso o resultado seja NaN:

```
return parseFloat(clean) || 0;
```

2 - Fazer que o valor padrão do input seja 0:

```
<input type="number" class="quantity" value="0">
```

Comment: Obg, funcionou perfeitamente agora

Comment: De nada, colega!